# what is difference between dijit and dojo

Tags: dojo

I am new to dojo . I see this term like dijit . What is the difference between it and dojo?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am sure it would help you if you read [Dojo Documentation part on Dijit](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/info.html). The first sentence says:

```
Dijit is a widget system layered on top of dojo.
```

Answer (score 8):

Dijit is a system built on top of Dojo that allows you to easily reuse/use reprogrammed widgets. Below is some example code that provides you a view of the relationship within the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
</script>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.Dialog" title="Hello Dijit!" id="someId"></div>
```

So here Dojo is loading Dijit's Dialog box and will apply the Dialog box to the element of "someId".